# Image Resizing HTML5

Tags: css, html

So I have images that I would like to take up the full screen in my HTML5 code. I have their height and width set to 100% which I assumed should have done resizing.

If I place images in that are 3240x480 they fit my phone just fine, but on the iPad the stretch the height it seems to fit but the width seems to stay at 320.

If I place in images that are 768x1004 they fit the iPad perfectly, but on the phone they display to large. I thought the 100% would do rescaling, but I guess I'm wrong.

So I tried setting the images with 768x1004 to width="window.innerWidth". That shrinks it down on the phone pretty well, except it still stretches past the bounds of the screen a bit. As for the iPad it shrinks the width down some so now there is a gap between the image and the wall of the screen.

Any ideas how to get a clean and simple auto resize to adjust to the screen preferably with just the 1 image. Or else how would I set it so there are multiple images and it puts in the image for the iPad size if its an iPad being used other wise the phone sized images if its a phone being used?

Thanks

Comment: Are your `img`s sitting inside of anything? Also, have you tried the css property `img { max-width: 100%; }`? See **[this article](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/)**.

Comment: @Nathan Ya they are inside of a <li>. Its because each image should take up the full screen and the <li> is to allow you to swipe left or right to go to the next image. I just gave that a try and it had the same issue as doing the width="window.innerWidth"

Comment: Maybe post your code, or load it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's going on. If you're doing a full-screen slideshow, you could look at **[backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)**, it's got that baked into it.

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty sure, that you can´t, without really ruin the quality of your picture resize the image. But I do know that you can use a script to redirect your user to the site that fits for their screen. See this site http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/info3.htm or Google "Screen redirect" and a several alternatives appear infront of your eyes! :))